# Deploy API gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I followed all the instructions from this guide.

https://www.obytes.com/blog/image-resizing-on-the-fly-with-aws-lambda-api-gateway-and-s3-storage

I got the URL after deploying the api gateway.

https://azqvbborn5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev

But getting this error when I visit the page mentioned above.

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

How do I test if the API is working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

The URL you provided looks like the URL for an API Gateway and stage not API Gateway, stage, and endpoint, which is what you want. For example

- **Hostname for my API**: https://idwe4id5y6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- **Hostname for my API w/stage path**: https://idwe4id5y6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/
- **Hostname for my API w/stage and endpoint path**: https://idwe4id5y6.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/stuff/things

To get the URL for an endpoint from the console, do this...

1. Select API Gateway from the Services menu.
2. Select your API Gateway from the list.
3. Select Stages from the menu on the left hand side of the page.
4. Expand the stage to see your endpoints
5. Select the HTTP method (Post, Get, etc.) for the endpoint you want the URL for.
6. The URL will appear at the top of the detail pane on the right side of the page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try https://azqvbborn5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/resize

You will get the {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error when you're not hitting an actual API Gateway endpoint verb.